# Firebird + Entity Framework 6 in Visual Studio 2012 / 2013. How do I get both visual & non-visual components to work?

Tags: firebird, entity-framework-6

Does anyone have Firebird working with Entity Framework 6 at both design time and run time?

I'm mainly using VS 2012, but I get the same results in VS 2013.

Depending on the components I install I can get either design time or run time to work, but not both together.

If I install the latest .net provider & DDEX provider from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/ then DDEX works at design time.

I can use server explorer to connect to a database & can create a model using Entity Framework.

But run time fails with the following error:

*The Entity Framework provider type 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbProviderServices, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.*

If instead I install the the nuget package PM> Install-Package FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient run time works, but I can no longer use server explorer or reverse engineer a database.

Comment: Could you try with `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient-EF6` instead?

Comment: I originally wrote a really long question listing everything that didn't work, but it seemed pointless. I assume from your answer you don't have design time and run time working together either.

Comment: No, my C# work is limited to SQL Server, I only use Firebird from Java. However I know there are several issues with combining DDEX with the 'wrong' FirebirdClient (this can be both with the Entity Framework version and the targetted .NET version). I will see if I can reproduce your problem, I will also notify Jiri Cincura: maybe he has an authoritative answer

Comment: To provide a bit more info, I'm using Jiri's example from https://github.com/cincuranet/EF6_Firebird, so I have used FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient-EF6. It runs fine, but I've had no success with DDEX & that version of the provider.

Comment: I tried it as well, with various combination, DbProviderFactory configs, things in gac and machine.config, etc, and the only conclusion I can make is that it simply doesn't work. It seems to indicate it will work with Entity Framework 5, but that doesn't work for me either. I'd strongly advise to file a bug at http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET

Comment: Thanks for trying it for me, bug logged - http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-554

Answer (score 0):

Just need to run the reg files depending of the architecture of the system (86 or 64). This files are in the source package (http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/DDEX%203.0.1/DDEXProvider-3.0.1.0-src.7z/download).

Note: Edit the %path% variable in the reg file to point to the correct folder in your system.